# Travelling inside Schengen zone without visa

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, europe

I lost my passport with Spanish study visa, now I have a new one without a visa and I want to travel in Schengen with my friends during Christmas, the flight company said its okay and that you don’t need to be checked for visa inside Schengen but I am still afraid if the police stopped me, what would happen in worst case scenario? Would they make me pay a finance or consider it as a violation or something? I am tottally legal in Spain and I have my university papers with me + photocopybof my old passport with the visa

Comment: The visa only applies to Spain.  What is legal in the rest of Schengen depends on your nationality.  It's true that there are hardly ever any border checks.

Comment: The legal situation differs, depending on which other Schengen country you are planning to visit. Currently, there are more or less regular immigration checks on many intra-schengen land borders. If you for some other reason are checked by the police when being in or when trying to enter other Schengen states and don't have a visa in your current passport, you must at least expect to be detained until your immigration status can be confirmed by the Spanish authorities.

Comment: I am from Jordan and the spanish visa is considered as Schengen I guess. I am travelling to Belgium, Amesterdam, Prague, Budapest and Bratislava

Answer (score 2):

I presume you have/had a Spanish national "D" visa. This allows you to travel in the Schengen area as if you had a multi-entry "C" visa for the entire Schengen zone, and days in Spain do not count against the 90/180 limit.

- There are no *systematic* immigration controls within the Schengen area. There may be random checks.
- You are required to carry valid papers when you cross internal borders, *even if there are no checks.*

If you have a Permiso de residencia expedido a nacionales de terceros países that should be enough.

Have you reported your lost passport to the Spanish authorities? Have they given you some sort of receipt for the report? What did they say?

Comment: O.m Yes I reported, i have the report and a certificate says that I am legal in Spain but it says in the same time that it cant be used outside Spain, I have my university papers, my first flight ticket to enter Schengen, my bank account, my student card..that’s all

Comment: @AshrafTaha, ask the Spanish authorities if a valid passport plus a valid permiso are enough to travel.The permiso can't replace a passport, can it replace the visa sticker?